# Use AWS IAM account for SSH login

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux, ssh, iam, ec2

A small admin team needs occasional SSH access to EC2 Linux instances on multiple AWS accounts (assumed role). These machines come and go dynamically so managing users via user_data or ansible is awkward. Also, the small number of admins makes it seem fiscally imbalanced to take on the load of a full user directory system. We do have them already managed by AWS IAM though.

I'd like to setup my EC2 Linux instances to allow login (and port tunneling) using IAM identities. The user accounts are typically in a different AWS account from the EC2 instance so we'd need to be able to do some sort of cross-account identity sharing I assume.

Ideally, SSH to the EC2 instance would be available to someone as soon as I add them to a role in the AWS Account's IAM configuration. Additionally, access would be removed when they are removed from the role.

I know AWS has services they provide to do this, but what I can't find evidence of is the ability to use ssh port forwarding to access web ports that aren't routed out of the network.

How can this be done?

Comment: I've finally found information about using AWS SSM for tunneling so maybe that solution may work sufficiently to provide the security level and flexibility I'm looking for.